# How can I execute a try statement again when KeyError is thrown in Python?

Tags: python

In this code, I want to execute **try** again when an exception occurs.

What are the various ways?

```
type_input = 0

print("Welcome to the fantastic Mud Shopping Mall, MADMUDSHOP!!")
print("(Select your member type.)")
print("1. Administrator \t 2. User ")

command = {
    1 : print_admin_home,
    2 : print_user_home
}

type_input = int(input())


try:
    command[type_input]()
except KeyError:
    print("You mistyped it!")
```

Comment: Put it inside a loop.

Comment: Wrap it around a while True loop

Comment: Thank you for kindly answer! I forgot that there is an "else" in the try syntax.

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put it in a `while` loop, that will loop forever :

```
command = {1: print_admin_home, 2: print_user_home}
print("Welcome to the fantastic Mud Shopping Mall, MADMUDSHOP!!")
while True:
    print("Select your member type:\n1. Administrator \n2. User")
    type_input = int(input())
    try:
        command[type_input]()
    except KeyError:
        print("You mistyped it!")
```

Comment: Thank you for the specific answer! Has been a great help to me!